# infer avro schema for BigQuery table load

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the java api, trying to load data from avro files into BigQuery.
When creating external tables, BigQuery automatically detects the schema from the .avro files.
Is there a way to specify a schema/data file in GCS when creating a regular BigQuery table for data to be loaded into?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create [manually the schema definition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#manually_specifying_schemas) with the [configuration.load.schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.schema), however, the documentation says that:

> When you load Avro, Parquet, ORC, Cloud Firestore export data, or Cloud Datastore export data, BigQuery infers the schema from the source data.

Comment: That's correct, BigQuery will automatically get the schema from the *alphabetically last* file. 
So if you have filea.avro (with field a and b) and fileb.avro (with field a and c) you are loading in one load job - BigQuery will load fields a and c from both files (in which case c, will be null for the rows in filea).
Additionally you could specify a schema, like F10 said, which may help if you don't want to load every column in the file, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was that the table existed already, and I did not specify the CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED.
You do not need to specify the schema at all, just like for the external tables